# Customize Mapbox snippet information layout

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I have been using Mapbox in a recent project of mine and I was just wondering if it is possible to customize the default marker information box.

[image: Mapbox Information box]

I was hoping there was a way use a custom xml layout so that I would be able to add other assets to the information box (Images, icons, etc). I have done a little bit of looking around but I cannot seem to see any references to this being done, is it something Mapbox supports?

I found this: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/2.2.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/views/MapView.InfoWindowAdapter.html

But how do I apply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are using a really old version of our SDK, please update to either `4.1.1` or `4.2.0-beta.5` for better performance along with new features an abundance of bug fixes.

You'll find [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/annotations/CustomInfoWindowActivity.java) useful for creating a custom info window.

```
mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
          @Nullable
          @Override
          public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {

            // return your info window view. 

            return view
          }
});
```